# Unitary in adjointable operators associated with equivariant Hilbert module

Tags: c-star-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, group-actions, hilbert-modules

Consider the following fragment from the article "[Tannaka–Krein duality for compact quantum
homogeneous spaces. I. General theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.6552.pdf)" by De Commer and Yamashita:

[image]

How exactly is $\mathcal{E}\otimes_{\alpha_{\mathbb{X}}} (C(\mathbb{X})\otimes C(\mathbb{G}))$ here a right $C(\mathbb{X})\otimes C(\mathbb{G})$ module? I am not sure what the notation $\otimes_{\alpha_{\mathbb{X}}}$ means here. Presumably, it refers to the inner tensor product of Hilbert modules, but I'm not sure how exactly this works because then we would need a $*$-morphism into the adjointable operators.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather easy; I think what is confusing is the sheer number of objects flying around.

What is $C(\mathbb X)$?  This is Definition 1.4 in the paper: this is a $C^*$-algebra with an ergodic action of $\mathbb G$.  So there is a coaction $\alpha_{\mathbb X}:C(\mathbb X) \rightarrow C(\mathbb X) \otimes C(\mathbb G)$, which is a unital $*$-homomorphism.

What is the interior tensor product?  In general, we have $E=E_A$ (a Hilbert $C^*$-module over $A$) and $F=F_B$ and a non-degenerate $*$-homomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow\mathcal L(F)$.  We then form $E\odot F$ and complete for the $B$-valued form
$$ ( e_1\otimes f_1 | e_2\otimes f_2 ) = (f_1 | \phi((e_1|e_2)) f_2). $$

In this setup, $\mathcal E$ is by definition a Hilbert $C^*$-module over $C(\mathbb X)$ and we consider the algebra $C(\mathbb X)\otimes C(\mathbb G)$ as a module over itself, and in particular identify the "compact" operators on $C(\mathbb X)\otimes C(\mathbb G)$ with the algebra itself.  Thus $\alpha_{\mathbb X}$ may be regarded as a non-degenerate (because it is unital!) $*$-homomorphism $C(\mathbb X) \rightarrow \mathcal L(C(\mathbb X)\otimes C(\mathbb G))$.  This allows us to form the interior-tensor product
$$ \mathcal E \otimes_{\alpha_{\mathbb X}} (C(\mathbb X)\otimes C(\mathbb G)). $$

(Then writing out the definition of $X_{\mathcal E}$ will show that it is an isometry, and hence well-defined.  That it is unitary then follows by the density condititon in Definition 3.1.)

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed more obvious than I thought.